# No funciona variable PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo un problema y es que en el siguiente codigo, la variable $data_verific_slider_unic no funciona, osea me aparece en el navegador cada vez que la llamo lo siguiente:

> Notice: Undefined variable: data_verific_slider_unic in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Aulended Plataforma\assets\tienda\req\slider.php on
>   line 90

La verdad no entiendo el motivo, porque cuando hay un registro en la db si funciona pero cuando hay dos, no funciona. Ayudenme por favor. La idea general era mostrar los registros de la db, pero tengo que validar y sacar el primero para poner el active en el class y despues sacar los otros (Si es que existen) y ponerlos. Les vuelvo a escribir el error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: data_verific_slider_unic in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Aulended Plataforma\assets\tienda\req\slider.php on
>   line 90

```
<?php 

//SISTEMA DEL SLIDER

    //Recolectamos los datos del slider

            //Recolectamos el primer dato del slider

                $slc_sld_unic_count = $mbd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) id FROM slider_comercios WHERE codigo_identificacion_comercio = :codigo_identificacion_comercio");

                $slc_sld_unic_count->bindParam(':codigo_identificacion_comercio', $codigo_identificacion_usuario);

                $slc_sld_unic_count->execute();

                    //Obtenemos la verificacion del sldier

                        $registro_slider_unic = $slc_sld_unic_count->fetchColumn();


                        if ($registro_slider_unic == 0) {

                            //Definimos el estado como false

                                $data_verific_slider_unic = 'false';

                        }elseif ($registro_slider_unic == 1) {

                            //Tomamos los datos del slider unico

                                $slc_sld_unic = $mbd->prepare("SELECT * FROM slider_comercios WHERE codigo_identificacion_comercio = :codigo_identificacion_comercio LIMIT 1");

                                $slc_sld_unic->bindParam(':codigo_identificacion_comercio', $codigo_identificacion_usuario);

                                $slc_sld_unic->execute();

                             //Repetimos el proceso para tomar el id

                                $tm_dt_sl_unic = $mbd->prepare("SELECT * FROM slider_comercios WHERE codigo_identificacion_comercio = :codigo_identificacion_comercio LIMIT 1");

                                $tm_dt_sl_unic->bindParam(':codigo_identificacion_comercio', $codigo_identificacion_usuario);

                                $tm_dt_sl_unic->execute();

                                while ($tm_dt_sl_unic_lb = $tm_dt_sl_unic->fetch()){ 

                                    $id_slr_unic = $tm_dt_sl_unic_lb['id'];

                                }    

                            //Definimos el identificador del slider primario

                                $data_verific_slider_unic = 'true';

                        }elseif ($registro_slider_unic >= 2) {

                            $sld_slc = $mbd->prepare("SELECT * FROM slider_comercios WHERE codigo_identificacion_comercio = :codigo_identificacion_comercio WHERE id != :id_slr_unic");

                            $sld_slc->bindParam(':codigo_identificacion_comercio', $codigo_identificacion_usuario);

                            $sld_slc->bindParam(':id_slr_unic', $id_slr_unic);

                            $sld_slc->execute();

                            //Definimos el identificador general

                                $ident_general_slider = 'true';

                        }


    //Terminamos la recoleccion de datos del slider

//FIN SISTEMA DEL SLIDER ?>
```

```
<section class="slider_comercio">
    <div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- The slideshow -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <?php 

            //Verificamos si existe un slider

            if ($data_verific_slider_unic == 'false') {

                ?><div class="carousel-item active">

                    <img src="../assets/tienda/assets/img/banner/banner-bg.jpg" alt="Aulended">

                </div><?php

            }elseif ($data_verific_slider_unic == 'true') {

                while ($sld_ms_lb_tl = $slc_sld_unic->fetch()){ ?>

                    <div class="carousel-item active">

                        <img src="../assets/slider/<?php echo $sld_ms_lb_tl["nombre_imagen"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $sld_ms_lb_tl["comercio_imagen"]; ?>">

                    </div>


                        <?php } 

                        //Tomamos los otros registros

                        switch ($ident_general_slider) {

                            case 'true':

                                //Mostramos todos los sldier

                                    while ($sld_slc_todos = $sld_slc->fetch()){ ?>

                                        <div class="carousel-item">

                                          <img src="../assets/slider/<?php echo $sld_slc_todos["nombre_imagen"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $sld_slc_todos["comercio_imagen"]; ?>">

                                        </div> 


                                        <!-- Controles del slider -->

                                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slider" data-slide="prev">

                                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>

                                            </a>

                                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slider" data-slide="next">

                                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>

                                            </a>

                                        <!-- Controles del slider -->

                            <?php   }

                            break;
                        }

            }



        ?>


      </div>


    </div>
</section>

<!-- Seccion del Slider Fin -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas declarando tu variable en un ámbito local dentro de un if(){}, procura declararla fuera de el, y usarla dentro(como lo estas haciendo). por eso es que te sale ese error de variable no definida.

```
//SISTEMA DEL SLIDER

//Recolectamos los datos del slider

        //Recolectamos el primer dato del slider


            $data_verific_slider_unic == '';// <-----la declaras aquí


            $slc_sld_unic_count = $mbd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) id FROM slider_comercios WHERE codigo_identificacion_comercio = :codigo_identificacion_comercio");
introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: No amigo, lo acabo de solucionar, era que hacia un if con valores estaticos (0 y 1) si habia dos registros, caia error porque no estaba en la condicional